# ASP.net File Upload To Populate A Table But Save All Files In Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an asp.net web application which saves all details entered and at the end sends an email with all the details including file upload functionality (all this works).

The issue I have is that a change is required to the file upload page.  I want to now be able to upload multiple docs so basically the user finds the file to upload then clicks an 'Add' button. The upload filed should then clear and a table should populate with the uploaded file(s) witht he action to edit or remove it.

As I said I have single file upload working using the code behind but I have no idea how to implement what I'm after so that all uploaded doc's are sent in my email.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">
          <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
               <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput" style="background-color: #ededed">
                    <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
               </div>
               <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file">
                    <span class="fileinput-new">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" title="Click to select a file."></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="fileinput-exists">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" title="Click to change the selected file."></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="file" name="..." id="fuAttachment" runat="server" />
               </span>
               <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" title="Remove selected file."></span>
               </a>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
          <asp:DropDownList ID="Step03WebTypeDD" runat="server" class="form-control">
               <asp:ListItem Value="- - Please select - -">- - Please select - -</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Requirements">Requirements</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Functional specification">Functional specification</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Page Content">Page Content</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Page Designs">Page Designs</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="Page Designs">Other</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-1">                                    
          <asp:LinkButton ID="UploadAddButton" runat="server" OnClick="Step05UploadAddButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success pull-right" ToolTip="Click to upload the file.">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
          </asp:LinkButton>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Code behind**

```
var file = fuAttachment.PostedFile;
if (file != null && fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName != "")
{
    var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
    Session["FileContent"] = content;
    Session["FileContentType"] = file.ContentType;
    Session["File"] = fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName;
    Session["AttachmentProvided"] = "Yes";
}
else
{
    Session["FileContent"] = "";
    Session["FileContentType"] = "";
    Session["File"] = "";
    Session["AttachmentProvided"] = "No";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you an idea on how to implement it... Store a list of object to your session..

MyFile object:

```
class MyFile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyFile()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Added view code

View:

```
<asp:ListView ID="uploadedFileList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%# Eval("Name")%></td>
            <td><%# Eval("ContentType")%></td>
            <td><asp:LinkButton Text="Remove" ID="lkbCommandAction" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' OnCommand="lkbCommandAction_Command" runat="server" /></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="tbl1" runat="server">
            <tr id="tr1" runat="server">
                <td id="td1" runat="server">File Name</td>
                <td id="td2" runat="server">Content-Type</td>
                <td id="td3" runat="server"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server">  
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Code Behind:

```
var file = fuAttachment.PostedFile;
            if (file != null && fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName != "")
            {
                var content = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                file.InputStream.Read(content, 0, content.Length);
                List<MyFile> myUploadedFiles = null;

                if(Session["UploadedFiles"] == null)
                {
                    myUploadedFiles = new List<MyFile>();
                }
                else
                {
                    myUploadedFiles = (List<MyFile>)Session["UploadedFiles"];
                }

                myUploadedFiles.Add(new MyFile()
                {
                    Content = content,
                    ContentType = file.ContentType,
                    Name = file.FileName
                });

                Session["UploadedFiles"] = myUploadedFiles;
            }
            else
            {
                Session["UploadedFiles"] = null;
            }

uploadedFileList.DataSource = myUploadedFiles;
uploadedFileList.DataBind();

protected void lkbCommandAction_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.CommandArgument == null)
        {
            /*TODO*/
        }
        else 
        {
            List<MyFile> myUploadedFiles = null;

                if(Session["UploadedFiles"] == null)
                {
                    myUploadedFiles = new List<MyFile>();
                }
                else
                {
                    myUploadedFiles = (List<MyFile>)Session["UploadedFiles"];
                }

                Guid removeId= (Guid)e.CommandArgument;
                MyFile fileToRemove = myUploadedFiles.FIrstOrDefault(ff => ff.Id == removeId);
                if(fileToRemove != null)
                {
                     myUploadedFiles.Remove(fileToRemove);
                }
                uploadedFileList.DataSource = myUploadedFiles;
                uploadedFileList.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

Since you now have a list of files in your session you can track the file names, content type, etc. of the uploaded files by the user and do what you want with them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how would I get it so it adds an entry for each document to a table in my view when the 'Add' button is clicked